# Convert a 2D array of int ranging from 0-256 into a grayscale png?

Tags: java, file-io, png, javax.imageio, grayscale

How can I convert a 2D array of ints into a grayscale png. right now I have this:

```
    BufferedImage theImage = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    for(int y = 0; y<100; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x<100; x++){
            theImage.setRGB(x, y, image[y][x]);
        }
    }
    File outputfile = new File("saved.bmp");
    ImageIO.write(theImage, "png", outputfile);
```

but the image comes out blue. how can I make it a grayscale.

image[][] contains ints ranging from 0-256.

Comment: I don't think you mean PNG since you aren't saving anything to a file of any format. You seem to be just drawing to the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image comes out blue because `setRGB` is expecting an RGB value, you're only setting the low byte, which is probably Blue, which is why it's coming out all blue.

Try:

```
BufferedImage theImage = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
for(int y = 0; y<100; y++){
    for(int x = 0; x<100; x++){
        int value = image[y][x] << 16 | image[y][x] << 8 | image[y][x];
        theImage.setRGB(x, y, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: still blue, I actually want it to come out grayscale now that I think about it.

Comment: that should be coming out as grayscale.. are you sure you're setting the pixel to the new value and not the old one?

Comment: Try passing `BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY` to the constructor and use the original code you had for the inner loop?

Comment: im not sure what was wrong, but it randomly started working. Thanks! haha

Answer (score 0):

I never tried but actually BufferedImage should be instantiated even in grey scale mode:

```
new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
```