# java how to convert a int[][] to an BufferedImage

Tags: java, bufferedimage

i have an 2D integer array, which i get from the BufferedImage method "getRGB()".
when i try to convert the 2D integer array back to BufferdImage, i get only a black picture.

This method

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++) {
            int pixel=matrix[i][j];
            System.out.println("The pixel in Matrix: "+pixel);
            bufferedImage.setRGB(i, j, pixel);
            System.out.println("The pixel in BufferedImage: "+bufferedImage.getRGB(i, j));
        }
    }
```

give this output:

```
The pixel in Matrix: 0
The pixel in BufferedImage: -16777216
The pixel in Matrix: 721420288
The pixel in BufferedImage: -16777216
The pixel in Matrix: 738197504
The pixel in BufferedImage: -16777216
The pixel in Matrix: 520093696
The pixel in BufferedImage: -16777216
The pixel in Matrix: 503316480
The pixel in BufferedImage: -16777216
```

why is every Pixel "-16777216"?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

the method which returns the integer Matrix

```
public int[][] getMatrixOfImage(BufferedImage bufferedImage) {
    int width = bufferedImage.getWidth(null);
    int height = bufferedImage.getHeight(null);
    int[][] pixels = new int[width][height];
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            pixels[i][j] = bufferedImage.getRGB(i, j);
        }
    }

    return pixels;
}
```

Comment: Does this help?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436931/convert-a-2d-array-of-int-ranging-from-0-256-into-a-grayscale-png

Comment: The format of your matrix values are wrong. Where did you get them? Can you show the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your pixels seem to be black with different alpha values. You have to use TYPE_INT_ARGB to not lose the alpha channel.

Comment: This was the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `TYPE_INT_RGB`, you can do it this way:

```
BufferedImage.getRaster().setPixels(xCord, YCord, Width, Height, IntArray);
```